# Why image is not displayed in browser when using react-img-mapper

Tags: reactjs, imagemap

I am using react-img-mapper from GitHub, but it is not displaying results, just showing an empty page in the browser.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ImageMapper from 'react-img-mapper';

    import "../assets/style.css";
    
    function AreaOperation() {
      const URL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/img-mapper/react-docs/master/src/assets/example.jpg';
      const MAP = {
        name: 'my-map',
        // GET JSON FROM BELOW URL AS AN EXAMPLE
        areas: [
          {
            id: "469f9800-c45a-483f-b13e-bd24f3fb79f4",
            active: true,
            title: "Hardwood",
            shape: "poly",
            name: "BB(1-4)",
            fillColor: "eab54d4d",
            strokeColor: "black",
            coords: [
              520.0646766169153,
              393.0348258706467,
              85.23880597014923,
              378.6069651741293,
              637,
              479,
              13.099502487562177,
              478.10945273631836,
              11.606965174129343,
              438.3084577114427
            ]
          }
        ]
      };
      
      return <ImageMapper src={URL} map={MAP} />
    }
    
    export default AreaOperation;
```

My packages are

```js
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-image-mapper": "0.0.15",
  "react-img-mapper": "^1.4.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

Comment: Can you also show how you're using `AreaOperation` in your code?

Comment: it is used in routing.
i.e<Route exact={true} path="/areaOperation" component={AreaOperation} />

and linked in header as
 <li><Link to="areaOperation">Area of Operation</Link></li>